# Is Prince Harry the son of James Hewitt?

Tags: united-kingdom

Similarity between the Prince and James Hewitt have always been questioned and strengthened after Princess Diana's affair with James was confirmed.

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-1167157/The-comeback-cad-Why-James-Hewitt-STILL-dropping-tantalising-hints-Prince-Harrys-paternity.html

Comment: Since citations and evidence are required around here, you might be better off calling Prince Charles and asking for a paternity test.

Comment: There is no evidence in the public domain. Although there is much rumour (indeed there are rumours that the royal family ran paternity tests http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-news/1432660/posts ).
I suspect you will find it hard to find clear evidence either way.

(Although I'm minded to say "who cares")

Comment: Our brains are very good at finding similarities, especially when someone hints us to see them... Prince Harry and James Hewitt simply have typical Northern European traits, I am sure you could find another million people that look like they could be Harry's father... (plus I do not think the resemblance is so striking)

Answer (score 9):

No, he is the son of Prince Charles:

According to this news source, this was confirmed by a blood test:

> Diana, who publicly admitted to her affair with Hewitt in a 1995 television interview, insisted that the dates of her affair with the officer meant he could not possibly be Harry's father, Simmons said.
> However, she was pressured to carry out DNA tests on both Harry and his elder brother, Prince William, to prove their paternity, the Sun said in its Wednesday edition.
> The tests showed that both princes had been fathered by Charles, the heir to the British throne

—[source](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-news/1432660/posts)

According to James Hewitt it is impossible because he started his relationship with Princess Diana *after* Harry was born:

> "There really is no possibility whatsoever that I am Harry's father.
> Although I was with Diana for a long time I must state once and for all that I'm not Harry's father
> "I can absolutely assure you that I am not."
> Prince Harry was "already walking" by the time his relationship with Diana began

—[source](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk/2273498.stm)

This was also confirmed by Diana's body guard:

> In a book by Diana's former police bodyguard Ken Wharfe, the rumours are also quashed.
>
> Mr Wharfe said the gossip used to upset the Princess.
>
> He said in his book: "The malicious rumours that still persist about the paternity of Prince Harry used to anger Diana greatly.
>
> "The nonsense should be scotched here and now.
>
> "Harry was born on 15 September, 1984.
>
> "Diana did not meet James until the summer of 1986, and the red hair, gossips so love to cite as proof is, of course, a Spencer trait."

—[source](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk/2273498.stm)

Comment: It is not clear that Simone Simmons's book *Diana: The Last Word* and its claim to be quoting something dramatic the by-then long dead Diana may have said to her energy healer which did not appear in Simmons's earlier *Diana: The Secret Years*, and then serialised in the Sun, with the serialisation reported by Agence France Press and repeated by Free Republic, really amounts to credible evidence.